# Can I license certain components of my software as MIT, but have the overall software be Copyleft?

Tags: gpl, mit, copyleft

I'm considering releasing the source code of an App as Copyleft, but would like some individual components (just not the core project) to be used under a more permissive MIT license.

How would this work? Can I have a top-level LICENSE file that's Copyleft, and then contain LICENSE files in sub-directories or at the top of files, and specifically state those directories (or particular files) are MIT licensed?

Would this cause issues for large organizations that scan for Copyleft software and prevent their developers from using it? I'd expect that, since it would be copied instead of downloaded through some package manager, it wouldn't be an issue for those developers, right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at [this answer](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/5477/release-code-with-mit-dependencies-under-gpl)?

Comment: Some companies have policies which prevent employees from using code under certain licenses, like [this example](https://opensource.google/documentation/reference/thirdparty/licenses). It is impossible to present a general behavior of 'large organizations', but usually they see code under permissive licenses much more favorable than code under copyleft licenses. Such companies might be using your code in the sub-directories under MIT license but ignore the top-level code under the copyleft license.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible provided you're the sole rightsholder, but it's fairly pointless: anybody downstream who modifies the software will need to release it *all* under GPL, as per (eg) [GPLv3](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html) s5c.

What makes more sense is to release the whole of your app under GPLv3, but in addition package and release your libraries *separately* under MIT, so that people wishing to use just those libraries can come and get them from you on permissive terms.  You might even want to put a note in your app's source that the libraries can be had directly from you on permissive terms.

If you follow this path, and your software becomes popular and you start to get contributions, note that you will need to take care handling contributions from people who send patches to the library.  If they have the library as part of the whole app, those patches will be under GPL, and you have no power to vary that, and so cannot add them to your MIT-licensed version.  This can be overcome by ensuring that all contributors to your library complete a CLA that explicitly permits release of their contributions under GPL and/or MIT, as you deem appropriate.

Comment: This seems strange to me. Plenty of software has sub-packages within their repo-- how is licensing a sub-folder of source not allowed, but having that same source in a separate repo with its own license (and importing it), any different? Seems like a package management/code organization question more than a licensing one. I read 5c and see how you could infer that, but I interpret it differently. To me, that's talking about the "viral" nature of GPL- if I use any GPL software, I need to license my *whole* work as GPL. But if I'm creating software from scratch, can't I license individual parts?

Comment: @Nathan I agree, and I repeat: if you're the sole rightsholder (ie, you created the software from scratch), you absolutely can release under mixed licenses.  But your downstream recipients can't, because they didn't create the work from scratch, and are therefore bound by the licences you've chosen - one of which says that when they modify and redistribute the work in turn, they must license the entire work under GPL to *their* downstream recipients.  So although you *can* do that, there's not much *point* in so doing.

Comment: Ah, okay, I think we're on the same page. I would disagree about there not being much point though-- I want to prevent others from easily copying my overall app/making major closed source changes to it/etc. However, I also want it so that other programmers, creating different apps, can use some of the patterns/components I create in their own (unrelated) app. So e.g., a generic Modal component would be MIT, an algorithm that I use but could be useful for others could be MIT, etc. People could copy that code (in a directory or specific file) w/o making their whole project GPL, right?

Comment: @Nathan licences do not inhere in code, but attach to recipients through the act of conveyance.  If these people get the component directly from you, either from your direct distribution of that component, or from your release of the mixed-license Android app, then yes, they could use the component under MIT.  But if they get the code from someone else's redistribution of your project, or from something based on that project, then no, they will get the component under GPL, and must then release any code incorporating it under GPL also.

Comment: Understood. So they could get it from my GitHub directly, but not from a fork, and use it as MIT licensed code. It does sound like releasing major components as separate libraries is probably useful, and I'll do that if any component is major enough for that, but this still seems like a potentially useful hybrid approach where I can immediately make stuff more available than GPL while not dealing with the overhead of breaking everything into separate repos/packages/libraries.

Comment: Couldn't I do a custom license, with a specific provision that MIT licensed components are exempt from having to release under GPL if you consume the code? Basically allowing you to sub-license specifically the only components that are already separately licensed, if you don't make changes to them? Eh, seems really complicated :/ Any better approach to the sort of hybrid approach I'm looking for, if my general ask here makes sense to you?

Comment: @Nathan not easily, because at that point it's not GPL, it's modified GPL, which makes the entire package difficult to use (see eg [this talk](https://lwn.net/Articles/782862/) (full disclosure: I wrote the article) where a professional licence analyst says he spends at most five **seconds** trying to work out if the licence on a piece of code allows its internal use).  Keep it simple.  License your app under GPL, package the individual components separately and release them under MIT, and put pointers in the GPL source to the components for those that want them under a permissive licence.

Comment: @MadHatter r.e. "they get the code from someone else's redistribution of your project, or from something based on that project, then no, they will get the component under GPL" can/do they not get it under GPL *and* MIT ? 5c even specifically says it doesn't invalidate permission to distribute under other licenses, if you have it.

Comment: @mbrig if you can show a clear line of "*it's all GPL except these bits which are MIT*", leading back through every single supplier, to the OP, then yes, I think you can do that.  But if at any stage someone just downloaded the code, or in some other way got it without an explicit licence agreement from upstream, then no, I think GPL s5c comes into play.  It's not enough, to my mind, to presume that each upstream provider intended to pass things on under MIT.  Hence my advice to the OP to make anything that they want to have available under MIT separately and explicitly available under MIT.

Comment: @MadHatter Unless someone in the chain violated the MIT license, every copy along the way would have included the MIT license file specifying that the sub-component/files are under the MIT license. I don't see why any presumption is necessary, the providers don't have a choice to *not* give you that component with the license, it would violate their obligations.

Comment: @mbrig because although it would have included the licence file, the presence of the file doesn't mean those conditions are the total summary of the license conditions on the covered code (qv); there is very good reason to think the GPL applies to them also.  So although the licence combination *permits* the continuing licensing of the MIT content under those terms, as you have pointed out, it also doesn't *require* it.  Without an affirmative declaration on the part of every upstream that this is what was intended, no, I don't think you can defensibly so conclude.

Comment: @MadHatter If I get an MIT licensed project that is in a subfolder of a GPL licensed project, I can still use the MIT license.  Nothing in the GPL prevents the code being transmitted to offer **additional licenses**.  Now, people could not use the MIT license and modify it and redistribute the modified version under pure GPL, but...

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I disagree, because without the clear assurances I refer to above, I don't know how you'd know it was MIT licensed - all you can know is that it's accompanied by the MIT licence text, which is not the same thing.  However, this is turning into a discussion in a comments field.  If you'd like to ask a new question about this, feel free to do so, but please let's not continue this discussion here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's possible.

For example, your overall software (assuming it's a standalone server process and not a library), can be licensed under GPLv2 or GPLv3, both strong copyleft licenses, but an accompanying library to communicate with your server software through sockets, can be licensed under the MIT license.

Another example, is that your overall software is a library licensed under LGPLv2.1, LGPLv3 or MPL2, which are all weak copyleft licenses, but you may include example code showing how to use your library, and this example code can be licensed under the MIT license.

Comment: Why the downvote? This seems a reasonable and correct answer.